# Sqlite - Programmatically increase database

Tags: sql, sqlite, generics, mobile, reflection

My question is at the same time easy and hard. I"ll try to explain the best I can.

I want to make possible for my entities to grow or to create new entities programmatically. Example:

```
public class Foo{
    public UUID id;
    public String fooName;
}
```

I want to programmatically add some field to my entity, for example the previous entity should become similar to this:

```
public class Foo{
    public UUID id;
    public String fooName;
    public String addedField;
}
```

I know I can't edit my class's text but I can programmatically add some fields to my database. The problem is that even if the database has `n` fields but the class has less fields, the adapter will not create a bigger class and the fields which are only in the database are lost.

I think I can do something like using only generics and reflection. And I'm pretty sure it will work, but is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Thanks all

**EDIT**

I forgot some more specifications:

I use SQLite for mobile developing. Lets talk about Android, which is the one I use most.

In android you have to convert the *cursor* object retrieved from the Database in a common object, modeled by a class.My problem is that I can also add columns and tables in the database programmatically, but they won't be retrieved in an object since the class hasn't been written in a .java file. (Same is for Windows phone).

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you be more precise about this "adapter" that you are using? What is it? SQLite is written in C. Even if you access it via C or a different language, you can send SQLite SQL Statements to alter tables. That is what I would call "Programmatically". Note that SQLite allows you only to change the name of a table and to add new columns. If you want to make more complicated changes, you will need several SQL Statements to achieve such changes. There are already many questions and answer about that here at stackoverflow.

Comment: I probably forgot some tags, since sqlite is usually used by mobile applications, you need an "adapter" for converting the sqlite cursor into a "real" object. The adapter takes from cursor all values and revert them into a real object. this adapter works with a class, and the problem is that adding columns programmatically with a sql statement, you don't add them to the class and this where the problem is: the object retrieved from the database will not have the added columns, I hope I explained it better

Comment: That makes it a bit more clear. However, I would still recommand to give the exact names of those tools you are using. That will increase the chances to receive the rigt answer.I think your assumption that sqlite is usually used by mobile applications is wrong. There are more applications for it. I use it for my websites and other small projects. I think sqlite is around for much longer than the smartphones.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't know that. thanks a lot for replying, I will fix my question asap. Thanks again, have a nice day!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323183/how-to-make-dynamic-column-using-android-sqlite-database